# Мэппинг в NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Нужно сделать простой маппинг:

```
public class UserStreet
{   
    public int id_User { get; set; }

    public int id_Street { get; set; }
}
```

Делаю так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="PrivatizationPlatform.Core"
                   namespace="PrivatizationPlatform.Core.Domain">
  <class name="UserStreet" table="USER_STREET" lazy="false">

    <property name="id_User" column="ID_USER" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="id_Street" column="ID_STREET" not-null="true"/>

   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Но знаю что чего то не хватает в маппинге, так как отношение id_User и id_Street, многие ко многим,они же и являются внешними ключами, так вот что же добавить в  мэппинг?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего вам вообще не нужно мапить данную сущность, так как она является промежуточной между сущностями User и Street (на это также указывает отсутствие дополнительных данных, кроме айдишников для связей). Хибер позволяет замапить только нужные сущности и в маппинге указать промежуточные таблицы, если они используются (как у вас для связи многие ко многим).

И еще в хибере давно уже появился fluent mappings and ConfORM в противовес "старым": xml and attributes.

Answer (score 1):

NHibernate поддерживает маппинг с помощью атрибутов, это намного удобнее чем xml-файлы.

например так:

```
[Property]
public int id_User { get; set; }
```

**UPD:** думаю [вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503798/hibernate-foreign-key-mapping-many-to-one) вы найдете ответ на свой вопрос

Comment: Хороший вариант, но мне надо сделать именно с помощью xml, просто использовать два подхода в одном проекте не очень хочется.

Comment: обновил ответ